# Registering OCX with regsvr32.exe and having it available for all users

Tags: registry, ocx, regsvr32

I have a third party web application that relies on a particular OCX file to be registered on the user's computer.  I have gone into the computer as an administrator and registered the file with the command:

REGSVR32 /S MyFile.ocx

This works fine and I am able to use the web application without issue.  In regedit I can see the control has registered properly.

However when another user logs onto the computer who is not an admin and tries to run the web application it does not work.

If I add that user to the administrators group and have them run the REGSVR32 command it works fine for them.  Unfortunately it really isn't feasible for me to allow all users to be administrators on their machines.

Is there a way I can register the OCX file with REGSVR32 and have it available to all users, even those without admin rights?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Usually regsvr32 registers CLSID info in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\software\Classes, so registration should be visible to all users.

The problem could be with your OCX.  It might do something on start up that prevents to open it for non-admin users.  For instance it requires to write something to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE registry, write to Windows directory, ...

You can check if this OCX is doing something for non-admin user by using [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) tool and check for ACCESS_DENIED errors.

In case if your OCX doesn't do anything under admin account, what you can try to do is to register you OCX under HKEY_CURRENT_USER lever by using [RegSvrEx](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3505/RegSvrEx-An-Enchanced-COM-Server-Registration-Util) tool.  This way your OCX will be registered under current_user_level

Comment: Thank you.  I logged into the machine in question using a standard user account and started Process monitor using "Run As" and supplying my administrator account.  The application did not work as expected but I did not see any ACCESS_DENIED messages in the Process Monitor tool.  Can you give me a brief description of what I should be doing in Process Monitor.  Also, I noticed that if the user logs into a machine that they have never logged into before they can run the application after the REGSVR32 command has been run.  It only doesn't work on PCs that already have a profile for the user.

Comment: When you open Process Monitor, I would recommend you turn on filter (Ctrl + L) and filter by "Process Name" and specify your process that contains your OCX control.  Then start your process with user account that has problem and check for "Result" Column.  Check for anything that is not "SUCCESS".  I hope it there will be some clue, why it fails.

Comment: You said "It only doesn't work on PCs that already have a profile for the user".  Let me ask you question, after user that never login to that machine runs app, then log off and log in again, are they able to run that app again.  This way they will have account created, and based on your observation they should not be able to open that app.

Comment: I figured it out.  I was registering the OCX from a location the non-admin user didn't have access to.  I modified my script so the file is copied to the local machine first, then registers it.  Works like a charm.  Thanks for your help!